# TestStack White GetParent Element

Tags: c#, ui-automation, white-framework

This is a 2 part question: 
1) I am trying to locate parent of element such that it could be any grand parent of the current element based on certain attributes like controlType.
Code:

```
control.GetParent<IUIItem>();
```

The above code gives me the immediate parent of the "control" element and not the grant parent that I desire like

```
control.GetParent<Tab>();
```

From this i Got to know that this API needs to know the parent element type before hand.
2) So I tried creating some kind of Utility of my own regarding this:

```
public static IUIItem GetParent(ControlType type, IUIItem control)
        {
            while (true) {
                control = control.GetParent<IUIItem>();
                Console.WriteLine(control.GetType());
                if (control.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(type)) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found match");
                    break;
                }
            }
            return control;
        }
```

So in the above Util method when I am trying to get type of the parent element it is returning something like this:
    Castle.Proxies.TabProxy
But I was expecting GetType to return me "Tab" as the type of the control. Not sure why does it returns Castle.Proxies.TabProxy. I was wondering if there is any way to identify control type of the element so that it can be cast to the relevant Control Type.
I am new to C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetType returns the System.Type of the control and not the actual control type. You can find out the Control Type of the control like this:

```
AutomationElement element = control.AutomationElement;
ControlType elementType =   element.Current.ControlType;
```

For getting the Control Type of the parent you can use this code:

```
AutomationElement parent = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetParent(control.AutomationElement);
ControlType parentType = parent.Current.ControlType;
```

Comment: you made my day mate..Thnx a Lot.